# Write rows in columns in file in Python

Tags: python, file, row

I have sentences,in a form of a string, that look like this :

First sentence

```
            hund                    
barked      4.51141770734e-07
bit         0.0673737226603
dog         0.932625826198
```

Second sentence

```
            hyi                     
biid        6.12323423324e-07
bok         0.0643253
dyfs        0.514586321
```

and I want to write them into columns into a file like this :

```
            hund                                    hyi     
barked      4.51141770734e-07           biid        6.12323423324e-07
bit         0.0673737226603             bok         0.0643253
dog         0.932625826198              dyfs        0.514586321
```

Instead of having them like this :

```
            hund                    
barked      4.51141770734e-07
bit         0.0673737226603
dog         0.932625826198

            hyi                     
biid        6.12323423324e-07
bok         0.0643253
dyfs        0.514586321
```

Any ideas?

Comment: These are very nice specifications. What is your question? Please edit your post to include your latest attempt, and folks will point you in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two lists of lines, `lines1` and `lines2`. If you have a string with multiple newlines, you can make a list of lines by calling `.split('\n')`.

Then, you can format them into parallel columns with string formatting:

```
lines = ['{:<40}{:<40}'.format(s1, s2) for s1, s2 in zip(lines1, lines2)]
```

Example:

```
a = '''            hund                    
barked      4.51141770734e-07
bit         0.0673737226603
dog         0.932625826198'''.split('\n')
b = '''            hyi                     
biid        6.12323423324e-07
bok         0.0643253
dyfs        0.514586321'''.split('\n')
lines = ['{0:<40}{1:<40}'.format(s1, s2) for s1, s2 in zip(a,b)]
print '\n'.join(lines)
```

Output:

```
            hund                                    hyi                         
barked      4.51141770734e-07           biid        6.12323423324e-07           
bit         0.0673737226603             bok         0.0643253                   
dog         0.932625826198              dyfs        0.514586321
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well!, However, I receive this error ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: Ah. I think you are using a slightly older Python. I fixed it to work. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

If it's string formatting you're after, you might want to look as [str.ljust](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) to make a string a certain length.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my aim is to present them like columns instead of rows.