# Position of sustring in list for python

Tags: python, string, list

I have two lists, one in german and the other one in english.
I want to find the position of the translation of a german word/phrase in the english list.

For example

```
german = ['Der', 'Hund', 'ist', u'groß', 'und', 'freundlich']
english = ['The', 'dog' , 'is', 'big', 'and', 'friendly']
```

I want to find for the substring "ist gross", which is translated as "is big", its position and the position of its translation and check if :

1. both of them are in the beginning
2. both of them are in the end
3. the german phrase is in the beginning and the english phrase at the end
4. the german phrase is at the end and the english phrase in the beginning

I have tried to use the first word from the german and the english and check if both are in the beginning.
I have also checked if the last word of the german and the english are both at the end.
I am stuck at 3 and 4.
Does any has any idea?

Comment: To quote a comment [from a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865404/write-rows-in-columns-in-file-in-python#comment20839324_14865404): "These are very nice specifications. What is your question? Please edit your post to include your latest attempt, and folks will point you in the right direction. Thank you."

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the position of the corresponding words in their respective list is the same. So you could just `zip()` them together;

```
In [1]: german = ['Der', 'Hund', 'ist', u'groß', 'und', 'freundlich']

In [2]: english = ['The', 'dog' , 'is', 'big', 'and', 'friendly']

In [3]: zip(german, english)
Out[3]: [('Der', 'The'), ('Hund', 'dog'), ('ist', 'is'), (u'gro\xdf', 'big'), ('und', 'and'), ('freundlich', 'friendly')]
```

The answer to your question #1 is:

```
In [4]: together = zip(german, english)

In [5]: together[0][0] == 'ist'
Out[5]: False
```

And for #2:

```
In [6]: together[-1][0] == u'groß'
Out[6]: False
```

Questions #3 and #4 violate the premise on which the lists are built, so they cannot be directly answered based on the lists.

**EDIT:**
To answer your last questions you need to build a german-english dictionary. Python happens to have a [dictionary type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) built-in.

```
In [3]: ge = {}

In [4]: for g, e in zip(german, english):
   ...:     ge[g] = e
   ...:     

In [5]: ge
Out[5]: {'Der': 'The', 'ist': 'is', 'und': 'and', u'gro\xdf': 'big', 'Hund': 'dog', 'freundlich': 'friendly'}
```

Question #3 in general now becomes:

```
In [6]: german[0] == 'ist' and german[1] == u'groß' and english[-2] == ge['ist'] and english[-1] == ge[u'groß']
Out[6]: False
```

Question #4:

```
In [16]: german[-2] == 'ist' and german[-1] == u'groß' and english[0] == ge['ist'] and english[1] == ge[u'groß']
Out[16]: False
```